# Find $\int_0^{2x} |t-x| dt$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Let $x \geq 0$, then
>
> $$\int_0^{2x} |t-x| dt = $$

Consider the case when $t \geq x$

$$\int_0^{2x} |t-x| dt = \int_0^{2x} (t-x) dt = \frac{(2x)^2}{2} - x \cdot 2x = 0$$

If $t<x$, then 
 $$\int_0^{2x} |t-x| dt = \int_0^{2x} (-t+x) dt = -\frac{(2x)^2}{2} + x \cdot 2x = 0$$

The problem is that the answer should be $x^2$. Please, help me find a mistake.

Comment: Neither $t\ge x$ not $t<x$ hold over the whole interval; try identifying the region where each holds and splitting accordingly.

Comment: Or you may try t-x |-> t. Then it is an even function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: split
$$
\int_0^{2x} |t-x|\, dt = \int_0^x |t-x|\, dt + \int_x^{2x} |t-x|\, dt.
$$

Comment: Thanks, now I got the answer!